# JSON Schema for restricting block occurrences inside of an array

Tags: json

Probably there are many question on JSON schema, however, I couldn't find an answer I was looking for.

I have a JSON message where the block inside FlagDetails array can come a max of 300 times. How do I restrict this using the schema which I have created below so that Time and UID can come max of 300 but max occurrences is 1 per array block.

JSON body:

```
{
  "SData": {
    "IData": {
      "IDatas": {
        "Flag": "Yes",
        "FlagDetails": [
          {
            "Time": "2012-07-06 09:30:00",
            "UID": 1234567
          },
          {
            "Time": "2012-07-06 09:30:00",
            "UID": 1234567
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JSON schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "SData"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "SData": {
      "title": "SData",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "IData"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "IData": {
          "title": "IData",
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "IDatas"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "IDatas": {
              "title": "IDatas",
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "Flag"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "Flag": {
                  "title": "Flag",
                  "type": "string",
                  "default": "",
                  "examples": [
                    "Yes"
                  ],
                  "minLength": 2,
                  "maxLength": 3,
                  "minOccurs": 0,
                  "maxOccurs": 1,
                  "pattern": "^.*$"
                },
                "FlagDetails": {
                  "title": "FlagDetails",
                  "type": "array",
                  "default": [],
                  "items": {
                    "title": "Items",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "Time": {
                        "title": "Time",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "",
                        "examples": [
                          "2012-07-06 09:30:00"
                        ],
                        "minOccurs": 0,
                        "pattern": "^.*$"
                      },
                      "UID": {
                        "title": "UId",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "default": "",
                        "examples": [
                          "12345678912"
                        ],
                        "minLength": 4,
                        "maxLength": 12,
                        "minOccurs": 0,
                        "pattern": "^.*$"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is "minItems" & "maxItems". I have used those and it works perfectly.

```
"FlagDetails": {
"title": "FlagDetails",
"type": "array",
**"minItems": 0,
"maxItems": 300,**
"default": []
```